# command to print indexed constants

Tags: macros, labels

I am writing a maths paper where I have a lot of constants. I am indexing them to differenciate them. Basically my text looks like

> blabla $c_1$ blablabla $c_2$ blabla $c_3$ blabla $c_1$ blabla $c_4$ blabla $c_5$ ...

I would like to have a commande, let say "\constant" such that each time I call it prints $c_i$ where $i$ is an increasing index. Also I would like to be able to use labels, like in my example above where $c_1$ appears more then one time.

Any idea of a good way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{const}
\setcounter{const}{0}
\NewDocumentCommand{\constant}{o}
 {% #1 = number (optional)
  \IfValueTF{#1}%    
  {$c_{#1}$}%
  {\refstepcounter{const}%
  $c_{\theconst}$}%
 }
\begin{document}
    blabla \constant{} blablabla \constant{} blabla \constant{} blabla \constant[1] blabla \constant{} blabla \constant{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a specific constant say `c_3`, then use `\constant[3]`

Comment: Great that works fine.
Just a remark. One can write: *blabla \constant{} blablabla **\constant{}\label{const:2}** blabla \constant{} blabla **\constant[\ref{const:2}]** blabla \constant{} blabla \constant{}*